# What kind of broad-leaved tree is this?

Tags: identification, trees

This tree seems like a good addition to a garden/landscaping project, but I've never seen it before. Leaves are turned down. I don't know if that's an aberration for this particular plant or characteristic of the species.

Any ideas what this is?

[image]

Comment: Did you buy it or was it a volunteer,  and where do you live?

Comment: It's not Morus albus pendula as the leaves are not toothed. Still looking for other possibilities

Comment: I spotted it in a yard and was interested. I live in central Mississippi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like a weeping form of [redbud](http://plants.usda.gov/java/profile?symbol=CECA4).

Comment: This [article](http://www.kansas.com/2012/03/31/2278483/redbud-boom.html) describes a Texas variety called the Traveller that I think this especially looks like.

Comment: or it could be the Lavender Twist Variety described here http://www.treesusa.com/Plantinfo/Ornamental/redbud,%20lav%20twist.pdf  either way, good ID